# How to create tables in MS Access database using Visual Studio Server Explorer?

Tags: visual-studio, ms-access

Is it possible to add new tables to an existing MS Access database from the Server Explorer window in Visual Studio?

I've seen videos on how to do exactly that with a SQL server database connection. You just right-click the table folder in the tree of database object types below the Database Connection item in server explorer. The choices on the context menu include "Add a New Table." Once you fill out all the details of the table columns in the associated VS table definition tab, you click something and run the auto-generated CREATE TABLE command against the database, and the table is created.

But when I try that with my MS Access database (connection successful, all the tables show up, etc.), the right-click menu does not show Add a New Table. I'm thinking that there is no way to create tables in an Access database through Visual Studio wizards or designers. Maybe all the database creation, structure, field definitions, and such things must be created through the MS Access program itself.

Am I missing something obvious? Is there a way to do it through VS? (I hope; it would be nice to create the tables through VS). Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending a long time on it, I conclude that there is no way to create new tables in an MS Access database by using Visual Studio designers and tools. Maybe this will help someone one day.